# How to check $exists in one to many relationship mongodb sails js?

Tags: mongodb, sails.js

Is there any way to find records that collection is empty?

For example please find below array. I want only that records with index "companydata" is empty. and also how can i get data that does not have empty "companydata" data.

Thanks in advance.

```
[
{
    "company_id": {
        "company_name": "C2",
        "slug": "c2",
        "is_organized": 1,
        "status": "1",
        "id": "5adf158f547f7f0314ca8b56",
        "companydata": []
    },
    "user_id": "5ab889aee74a151b50d04ec1",
    "status": "0",
    "id": "5ae014e7432e85298081be0b"
},
{
    "company_id": {
        "company_name": "My Compnay",
        "slug": "my-compnay",
        "is_organized": 1,
        "status": "1",
        "id": "5ad442d98a0e0c1358ca93df",
        "companydata": [
            {
                "name": "Bhavesh Amin",
                "company_id": "5ad442d98a0e0c1358ca93df",
                "status": "0",
                "id": "5ad442da8a0e0c1358ca93e0"
            }
        ]
    },
    "user_id": "5ab889aee74a151b50d04ec1",
    "status": "0",
    "id": "5ae01388432e85298081bdf8"
},
{
    "company_id": {
        "company_name": "Organization Name",
        "slug": "organization-name",
        "is_organized": 1,
        "status": "1",
        "id": "5ad08f9b938d1131eceea624",
        "companydata": [
            {
                "name": "Helen H. Langley",
                "company_id": "5ad08f9b938d1131eceea624",
                "status": "1",
                "id": "5ad08f9b938d1131eceea625"
            }
        ]
    },
    "user_id": "5ab889aee74a151b50d04ec1",
    "status": "0",
    "id": "5ad42a5f52851a2b1449db2d"
},
```

]

Comment: Try this query: `db.collection.find({a:{$size:0}})`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But its not work for me.
Actually I have query like this:

`Users.find({a:{$size:0}}).populate("a")`

Comment: please show me your result?

Comment: [
  {
    "applyjob": [],
    "id": "5aba35d0f7cd3410f4ed30e9"
  },
  {
    "applyjob": [
      {
        "user_id": "5ab88dfde74a151b50d04ecf",
        "createdAt": "2018-04-11T05:37:41.952Z",
        "id": "5acd9f25738d15266cbe42eb"
      }
    ],
    "id": "5acd9f06738d15266cbe42e2"
  }
]

Comment: While using $size:0 its gives error :

Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $size